# How to chart d3 venn diagram with two distinct sets?

Tags: d3.js, venn-diagram

I'm trying to draw venn diagram in d3 from the post as below.

http://bl.ocks.org/bessiec/986e971203b4b8ddc56d3d165599f9d0

I used the data as below.

```
  var sets =[
                     {sets:["students"], figure: 600, label: "students", size: 600},
                     {sets:["pass"], figure: 455, label: "pass", size: 455},
                     {sets:["students","pass"], figure: 455, label: "", size: 455},
                     {sets:["students","fail"], figure: 145, label: "", size: 145},
                     {sets:["pass","fail"], figure: 0, label: "", size: 0},
                    {sets:["fail"], figure: 145, label: "fail", size: 145},

                ];
```

[image]

I want that students pass + fail must get into the students, how to shall i do that with the above library.

There are 600 students, of which 455 passed and 145 failed. then the two circles must be in students. How shall i achieve it using the above library, if not is there any d3 library to draw venn diagrams of such sceanarios.

Comment: If pass is 455 then it's students i.e. the sum of girls and boys that passed - so why would pass be *within* boys when boys is a subset of pass ?

Comment: I dont know the whole implementation of the algorithm but still i want to achieve what you are saying i.e. the pass circle must be within boys and girls but how to achieve that using the library that is implemented in d3.